# recuperando array com PDO

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo, aplicação-web

Estou com um problema que já passei por ele antes mas não me lembro como resolvi.
O objetivo é comparar duas tabelas do banco e retornar apenas os valores correspondentes entre as duas, no meu caso **nome** e **id** do usuário que esteja em uma equipe.
Minha classe **Membros** possui **id_membro** e **id_equipe** e nela chamo essa função

```
public function recuperaMembros(){

    $query = "
    SELECT 
        u.nome, u.id
    FROM
     usuarios AS u
    JOIN 
        membros AS m 
    ON 
        u.id = m.id_membro
    ";

    $stmt = $this->db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindValue(':id_membro',$this->__get('id_membro'));
    $stmt->execute();

    return $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

que me retorna

> ```
> Array
> (
>     [0] => Array
>         (
>             [nome] => kaue33
>             [id] => 24
>         )
>
>     [1] => Array
>         (
>             [nome] => kaue44
>             [id] => 25
>         )
>
> )
> ```

Mas como podem ver, um array contem o restante dos arrays, que no caso seria o retorno do fetchAll, logo não consigo utiliza-lo normalmente com índices como por exemplo

```
    $membros = $membro->recuperaMembros();
    $this->view->membros = $membros;
```

e apartir dai usa-lo normalmente como $this->view->membros['nome']; por exemplo, como resolver esse problema de array bidimensional ? sei que tem uma maneira para receber como um array comum apenas.
Pois se eu acessar $this->view->membros[0]['nome'] tenho acesso ao array que gostaria de ter, mas ficaria muito extenso e inviavel recuperar um array praticamente como matriz.
 Se puderem ajudar agradeço.

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que entendi você só precisa trazer uma única linha do banco de dados. se for só isso, você poderia limitar melhor essa sua Query usando o WHERE ou LIMIT 1. 
Outra questão que puder reparar é que você está usando o fetchAll() que no caso retorna toda a consulta do seu bando de dados. se for para trazer uma única linha experimente usar apenas o fetch().

Comment: realmente preciso de todas os registros, por exemplo, uma equipe pode ter ate 6 membros por exemplo, mas caso ela tenha dois preciso dos dois, ou seja, eu capturo o id da equipe, no meu bd possuo uma tabela equipe e outra tabela membros, ao comparar membros com o id do usario de determinada equipe eu quero retornar todos os membros. sei que tem uma maneira mas não consigo me recordar. Por exemplo, como posso retornar esse array de nomes e id em um unico array que não seja bidimensional?